# Why number of Support vector does not change in SVM?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am a newbe in scikitlearn lib. I am using a SVM bi-class to do pattern classification.
My data set contains 1000 samples (500 by class) but feautres number is very high (3000).

I divide the datset into 3 parts: trainset 800 samples, validset 100 samples and test set is 100 samples.

I am using this code:

```
class1=numpy.genfromtxt("class1.csv",delimiter=',');
class2=numpy.genfromtxt("class2.csv",delimiter=',');

trainset=numpy.concatenate((class1[0:400,:],class2[0:400,:]));
validset=numpy.concatenate((class1[400:450,:],class2[400:450,:]))
testset=numpy.concatenate((class1[450:500,:],class2[450:500,:]))

targettrain=numpy.reshape(numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((1,400)),numpy.ones((1,400))*2)),(800,));
targetvalid=numpy.reshape(numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((1,50)),numpy.ones((1,50))*2)),(100,));
targettest=numpy.reshape(numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((1,50)),numpy.ones((1,50))*2)),(100,));

clf=SVC();
clf.fit(trainset,targettrain);

SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, class_weight=None,coef0=0.0,decision_function_shape=None,degree=3,gamma=.1,kernel='rbf',
            max_iter=-1,probability=False,random_state=None,shrinking=True,tol=0.001,verbose=False);

print clf.score(validset,targetvalid)

print clf.n_support_
```

here is my data [data class1 and class2](http://www.filedropper.com/data_37)
I remark that the number of vector support does not change even when I change gamma or C.
Support vector is always [270 268].
What is the signification? is it a problem of curse dimensionality? I read that SVM can work even with data having high dimensionality?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the data you provided - changing either `C` or `gamma` causes the number of support vectors to vary as expected. Could you show exactly how you are generating `trainset` and `targettrain`?

Comment: @ali_m, I edited my code.

Comment: I still can't reproduce what you're seeing with the exact code above. For example, if I initialize with `clf = SVC(C=1)` (default), I see `clf.n_support_ == array([270, 268], dtype=int32)` after calling `clf.fit(trainset,targettrain)`. If I initialize with `clf = SVC(C=0.1)`, I see `clf.n_support_ == array([371, 367], dtype=int32)`. Likewise, varying `gamma` also changes the number of support vectors. What values of `C` and `gamma` have you tried? Perhaps you're not varying them enough (try varying them by at least an order of magnitude).

Comment: @ali_m, My code is not correctly design. I have to call `clf.fit(trainset, targettrain)` after  `SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, class_weight=None,coef0=0.0,decision_function_shape=None,degree=3,gamma=.1,kernel='rbf',max_iter=-1,probability=False,random_state=None,shrinking=True,tol=0.001,verbose=False);`

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're trying to set the parameters of the classifier you've instantiated using `SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, ...,‌​verbose=False);`, but instead this creates a *new* classifier instance that isn't bound to any variable name. What you ought to be doing is initializing `clf` with your desired parameters, e.g. `clf = SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, ...,‌​verbose=False);`. Also, it doesn't make any sense to try to change the parameters *after* you've already fitted your classifier to your training set.

Comment: @ali_m, Yes. I see. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though in this line:

```
SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, class_weight=None,coef0=0.0,decision_function_shape=None,
    degree=3,gamma=.1,kernel='rbf',max_iter=-1,probability=False,random_state=None,
    shrinking=True,tol=0.001,verbose=False);
```

you are trying to set the parameters for the `clf` classifier you already instantiated. However, what this actually does is to create a *new* `SVC` instance that isn't bound to any variable name. That line therefore has no effect on the behavior of `clf`.

A second problem is that you're trying to change the parameters *after* you've already called `.fit` on your training data, which doesn't really make any sense.

What you should do instead is pass your desired set of parameters when you first instantiate `clf`:

```
clf = SVC(C=1,cache_size=200, class_weight=None,coef0=0.0,
          decision_function_shape=None,degree=3,gamma=.1,kernel='rbf',max_iter=-1,
          probability=False,random_state=None,shrinking=True,tol=0.001,
          verbose=False);

clf.fit(trainset,targettrain)   # etc.
```